# TFS2015, Team Explorer Everywhere and Kerberos - Unable to authenticate

Tags: linux, tfs-2015

I'm trying to connect to our on premise TFS 2015 14.0.24606.0 (Tfs2015.Update1.RC1) server from Red Hat Linux using Team Explorer Everywhere 14.0.2 and Kerberos authentication.

However, it doesn't work. The TEE client either doesn't support Kerberos or I am using the wrong syntax. Below is what I have done.

First, I grab the Kerberos ticket using kinit.

```
kinit  dnolan@COMPANY.ORG.UK
Password for dnolan@COMPANY.ORG.UK:
[dnolan@MYLINUXVM TEE-CLC-14.0.2]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_502
Default principal: dnolan@COMPANY.ORG.UK

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
01/27/16 10:24:24  01/27/16 20:24:29       krbtgt/INTERNAL.COMPANY.ORG.UK@INTERNAL.COMPANY.ORG.UK
    renew until 02/03/16 10:24:24
```

Then, following this guide (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx), I create a new work space called Beta1 and point it towards the project collection in TFS.

```
 ./tf workspace -new Beta1 -collection:http://tfs.internal.COMPANY.org.uk:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection
 Access denied connecting to TFS server http://tfs.internal.COMPANY.org.uk:8080/ (authenticating as dnolan)
 Username: ^C
```

I believe the command I want to run is :`tf profile -edit -boolean:useDefaultCredentials=true  ProfileName`

However this command doesn't seem to exist in the latest version of Team Explorer Everywhere 14.0.2.

I found 'tf profile' command on this MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190725(v=vs.120).aspx) but it appears this is actually for an older version.

Enabling Basic Authentication isn't really an option.

Documentation for this client doesn't exist as far as I can tell so any help with this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Please check this case, "tf profiles were removed.  The default is to always attempt to use default credentials (Kerberos)." https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91450db5-3d36-4275-9ec8-7ab35013c258/teeclc-kerberos-regression?forum=tee

Comment: Hi Cece, thank you for your response.

I still can't get this to work even if it does use Kerberos by default.

From what I can tell the TEE CLC doesn't appear to use or know about the authenticated Kerberos ticket I've already got.